# Cant set the property (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have property, and i need to refresh View always when property is changed, but it doesnt work

```
 public WriteableBitmap OriginalBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(1280, 720);
private Image OriginalImage = new Image();
public Image Original
{
    get { return OriginalImage; }
    set
    {
        this.OriginalImage = value;
        base.RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

XAML

```
 <Image Grid.Row="1"
           Grid.Column="1" 
           x:Name="OriginalImg"
           Source="{Binding Original}"
           DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewModel}"/>
```

Im using MVVM libs for `RaisePropertyChanged`

And method

```
public async Task<bool> ApplyEffectAsync(StorageFile file)
{

        fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        OriginalBitmap.SetSource(fileStream);
        Original.Source = OriginalBitmap;
}
```

`Original` always `null`

Why? And how to fix?

Comment: where and how OriginalImage is defined?

Comment: Im updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the name of the property into the RaisePropertyChanged function. It uses that name to tell the UI that if it's bound to a property with that name, go get the updated value.

[Here is the Article on RaisePropertyChanged from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.entity.raisepropertychanged(v=vs.91).aspx)

It should look something like this

```
public Image Original
{
    get { return OriginalImage; }
    set
    {
        this.OriginalImage = value;
        base.RaisePropertyChanged("Original");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i read that, but i cant understand how its work. Im wrote  `base.RaisePropertyChanged("OriginalImg");` where `OriginalImg` is `x:Name="OriginalImg"` on view

Answer (score 0):

At first, change `SetSource` to `SetSourceAsync`

```
await OriginalBitmap.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
```

At second, I guess you don't initialize your `Original` property from your Page.

If you use MVVM - initialize this property.

```
((this.DataContext as MyViewModel).Original = myImage;
```

where `myImage` it's

```
x:Name="myImage"
```

If you don't use MVVM, change the ImageSource directly:

```
myImage.Source = OriginalBitmap
```

At third, if you use MVVM, you can change the property type to

```
public BitmapImage Original
{
    get { return _original; }
    set
    {
        _original = value;
        base.RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}

...

 Original = OriginalBitmap;
```

and in XAML use this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Original}"
       ....
```

Comment: Cant change  type `Image` to `BitmapImage` or `Writable BitmapImage` because cant convert Xaml.Image to Bitmap

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things needs to be corrected:

Firstly, it is recommended setting the `MainViewModel` instance as page's datacontext. Please don't set the ViewModel as `Image` control's `DataContext` and don't bind `ViewModel` as `StaticResource`. You can set it in XAML like below:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel"/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

Or you can set it on code-behind:

```
MainPageViewModel ViewModel=new MainPageViewModel();
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = ViewModel;
}
```

Secondly, [Image.Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.source.aspx) is of type `ImageSource`. To set this property requires an instance of `BitmapImage` or `WriteableBitmap`. So, `Original` object should be changed from `Image` to `BitMapImage` or `WriteableBitmap`. You can use the following codes to convert a `StorageFile` to `WriteableBitmap`:

```
IRandomAccessStream randomStream=await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(500, 500);
bitmap.SetSource(randomStream);
```

Thirdly, like @Anthony Russel said. the MVVM lib might need to know the propertyName of your property.

**Update**: Your ViewModel class should be similar like this:

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public WriteableBitmap _original;
    public WriteableBitmap Original
    {
        get { return this._original; }
        set
        {
            this._original = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Original");
        }
    }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    { }
    public MainPageViewModel(WriteableBitmap original)
    {
        this.Original = original;
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And Xaml:

```
<Page.DataContext>
   <vm:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel"/>
</Page.DataContext>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Image Source="{Binding Original}"
               x:Name="OriginalImg"
               ></Image>
        <Button Name="myBtn" Click="myBtn_Click" >Click Me</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: If I have a few `Datacontext`s` whether to make `MainViewModel` as in your example?

Comment: And im have code for convert `StorageFile` to `WriteableBitmap`.  But What parameter must be in `RaisePropertyChanged()`? Im try `"Original"`, try `"OriginalImg"`(Like on my View page)

Comment: If you have a few Datacontext, set DataContext in code-behind. And set the datacontext on image controls's parent panel(e.g. myGrid.DataContext=ViewModel.).

Comment: If you didn't use [CallerMemberNameAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.105).aspx). Pass "Original" as parameter for `RaisePropertyChanged()`.

Comment: I have noticed that my setter doesn start. And when i use `Original.Source = OriginalBitmap;` he goes to get method. Why he never set my image?

Comment: I know it's a little confusing. `Image` is the class for Image Control not for an Image instance(e.g. a JPG picture). So, you are binding an `Image` Control to `Image.Source`. To fix the problem, change `Original` and `OriginalImage` type to `Bitmap` or `WriteableBitmap`.

Comment: Im tried but have compile error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap` Because on View i have Xaml.Image and Binding to WriteableBitmap

Comment: I've updated the answer, Please check it, If you still have no idea of the error, maybe share a demo through online Repository(e.g. Github). I'll research on it.

Comment: But u cant Binding Xaml Image to Bitmap or WriteableBitmap

Comment: Setting the `Image.Source` property requires an instance of the `BitmapImage` class, which you also must construct. Please refer to [Setting Image.Source using code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.aspx).